# GPO vs Registry

Tags: gpo

I'm a new to Windows Administration. Is it true that all the GPO's affect registry keys in some way? Are there any GPO settings that don't affect registry keys at all? I apologize for asking a very generic qn.

Answer (score 0):

In very short: Yes, there are.

Slightly longer answer:

Group Policy Object consist of 2 parts: policy (a true GPO) and preferences (called GPP)

Policy settings are in 99,9% of cases written into a target machine registry.

Preferences on the other hand can set a lot of things:

- create/ delete a folder
- add a printer
- add a local user
- etc....